# Android Preferences: Is it possible to optimize OnPreferenceChangeListener?

Tags: java, android, optimization, android-preferences

Currently I have the codes like this:

```
back.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //DO STUFF
        return true;
    }
});
music.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //DO OTHER STUFF
        return false;
    }
});
sound.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        //DO MORE STUFF
        return true;
    }
});
```

Is it possible that there's a way to optimize this piece of code like this somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: kind of depends on what you do in your listeners

Comment: I want my class, which we will call it "Foo", implement `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`. I wanted to make the garbage collector happy by 'concentrating' the amount of calling `new OnPreferenceChangeListener()` into one place (meaning that all variables will be set as `setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this)`), instead of sticking them within some of the `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` helper functions.

Comment: So, there's no answer to this?

Comment: as a matter of fact, i don't understand where the issue is, here

Comment: Just wanted to consolidate all of the implements in the methods mentioned into one big class that implements `OnPreferenceChangeListener()`. That's all. Are the methods mentioned above called anomyous inner classes?

Comment: yes, they are anonymous classes. other ways of performing the same action is to have `this` implement the interface, make a nested class or an external class implement the interface.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is nested class. Why didn't I think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to njzk2, I was given a hint on how to consolidate all the implemented methods into one big object. Just make a nested class and use that to implement the interfaces.